# Common eigenvector of commuting unbounded operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $T$, $S$ be two self-adjoint linear operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with pure point spectrum.
Then $T$ and $S$ commute if and only if they have a complete set of common eigenvectors.

This is the full statement I want to prove. In the case of bounded operators this would be fine. My problem now is the unbounded case. I may tell you my thoughts for the first implication:

Let be $\phi\in D(T)$ an eigenvector from $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then we know, since $T$ and $S$ commute:
$$ TS\phi=ST\phi=S\lambda \phi=\lambda S\phi $$
Now, here is my problem: Can I assume (and why) that $\phi\in D(S)$ just given that $T,S$ commute and $\phi$ is an eigenvector of $T$? Maybe this is quite simple but I don't get it at the moment...

Comment: What is $D(S)$?

Comment: The Domain of the Operator $S$

Comment: What is your _definition_ of when unbounded (self-adjoint) operators commute?

Comment: The spectral Measure of these Operators commute, or $[e^{itT},e^{isS}]=0$ for all $t,s\in \mathbb{R}$, or $TS=ST$ including the equality of the domains.  
As far as I know, they are equivalent.

Comment: So another question: how do _you_ define $e^{itT}$?

Comment: With the general Spectral Theorem:  $$ e^{itT}=\int_{\sigma(T)} e^{it\lambda} dE(\lambda)$$

Comment: Okay, so you are happy with resolutions of the identity.  If $T$ has pure point spectrum, what special form does $E$ take, and hence what special form does $T$ take?

Comment: So $E(\{\lambda \})$ is the projection on the Eigenspace to  $\lambda$. And we can write $T\phi=\sum_i \lambda_i\langle\phi,\phi_i \rangle \phi_i$  where $\{\phi_i\}_i$ is an orthonormal basis composed of eigenvector to eigenvalues $\lambda_i$.

Comment: Okay.  Similarly $e^{itT}\phi = \sum_i e^{it\lambda_i} (\phi|\phi_i) \phi_i$.  If this commutes with $e^{itS}$, which has a similar form, for all $t$, then you can perform calculations with _bounded_ diagonal operators which will lead to the result you want.  (Also $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\lambda_n| = \infty$).

Comment: Okay. Then i will try solving this, on that way. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewDaws: You certainly can't conclude that $|\lambda_n|\to\infty$. For example, the set of eigenvalues could be $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: You can *not* conclude that $\phi\in D(S)$ from the fact that $\phi$ is an eigenvector of $T$; for example, if $T=1$, then this assumption says literally nothing on $\phi$. (Similarly, even if you knew that $\phi\in D(S)$, I'm not sure if your calculation is getting you anywhere. You could conclude that $S\phi\in N(T-\lambda)$, but what next?) I think a more abstract approach would work better; for example, both operators can be made multiplication operators by the same unitary transformation.

Comment: Mhm, okay. I know that theorem you are talking about, thanks for the help. Hope i will get some results out of this

Comment: @ChristianRemling:  Ah.  I think this comes down to what exactly we mean by "pure point spectrum".  I am following [Schmüdgen, Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789400747524) and assuming (maybe wrongly) that what the OP means is the same as "purely discrete spectrum" (meaning $\sigma(T)$ consists only of eigenvalues of finite multiplicity with no finite accumulation point).  Proposition 5.12 characterises such operators.

Comment: @MatthewDaws: I don't think there's any ambiguity in the terminology. Of course, as you point out, "pure point spectrum" and "purely discrete spectrum" are two different things, but it doesn't seem plausible to assume that the OP must be meaning the latter when he said the former.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment. This has been proven as proposition 6.6.2 on p. 233 of the book *Hilbert Space Operators in Quantum Physics*, 2nd ed. by Blank, Exner and Havlíček.

> A set $\mathcal{S} = \{A_j\}_{j=1}^N$ of commuting self-adjoint operators on a separable [Hilbert space] $\mathcal{H}$ with pure point spectra is a CSCO [complete set of commuting operators] *iff* $\operatorname{dim}P^{(n)} = 1$ holds for all $\{k\}_n \in K_N.$

CSCOs, $P^{(n)}$, ${k}_n$ and $K_N$ have been defined in the text.